# Button issues xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have buttons created by loop and each button it corresponds to a desk, so i have to able when i click a button i have to design spesific row of database

how i add buttons:

```
for (int i = 1; i < terasmasasayisi; i++)
        {
            var buttonteras = new Button
            {
                Text = i.ToString(),
                HeightRequest = 45,
                WidthRequest = 45,
                Margin = 5,
                BorderRadius = 100,
            };

            teras.Children.Add(button);
        }
```

If i can set a relationship between the table number and i(desknumber), I can do this according to the id from my database.

im so confused

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times.  Your previous question was closed for lack of detail - this question has the EXACT same problem.  Please read [ask] for guidance on improving your questions.

Comment: yes my perivious question is closed so now i asked with more detail